# make two columns the same length based on certain time intervals in excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, large-data

I have two excel sheets with two columns 1- data and time, 2- flow data. they have two different lengths (911315 rows, 14212 rows) because data was collected at different time intervals. I need to make the two flow columns the same length (time does not need to be the same). I used `=MOD(SECOND(D911296),65)=0` but it filters out same rows as `=MOD(SECOND(D911296),70)=0` or any other number. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Your two formula doing same thing expect dividing by `65` and `70`.

Comment: I know but the denominator is changing so the number of rows that meet the criteria should change, right? but it does not...

Comment: If time doesn't need to be the same, why not just use the first 14212 rows of both columns?

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is. You tried MOD on the time column, but that has nothing to do with making the column the same size, which is what your question is about. Please explain the logic you need in getting the correct data. Do you want to increase the size of the smaller column / decrease the size of the bigger. What should be the logic doing this? What's important to know about these dates / timestamps, what's the reason of the size difference?